# Python | GAE | Finding email size before sending admin mail?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Admin mail has a limit of 16kb on size, is there anyway to figure out email size in python gae before sending it to admins? I want to send multiple emails instead of 1 incase size exceeds.

Other option is to try sending mail and track exception and on exception break email but pre-processing will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sys.getsizeof(object[, default])
```

[getsizeof](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof)

I've not used mail in gae but presumably you can get the size of the contents you want to send, add that to the size of an empty mail and that might work.